# MS Access Export Specifications (row and column delimiters)

Tags: export-to-csv, delimiter, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to do an export from MS Access where the data from my table is delimited by column with Ñ but also to include a row delimiter ó  . Is this possible in Access? I see where I can change the column delimiter but not the row. I have intermediate knowledge of Access. Is it also possible to have the file come through as one long string using the row delimiter of course?

Comment: You can just export it the default way and open the text file and replace all row delimiters as you want. And save it.

Comment: I was thinking of something more automated. I ended up putting in code that does what you suggest, but then I open each file, read each line and add my row delmiter then write to a new file.